# How do I clean my git to simply be a working and production branch?

Tags: git

I've been attempting to back track my git work so that I have a production and working branch. I didn't do so well though. Using the git gui(which I've never touched before) I determined my history loks like this:

[image: GIT]

I'm not sure how I ended up with 3 branches but I believe one is my local copy?

My steps to get here were

```
$ git checkout origin/production
$ git reset --hard {{hash of commit I want production to be at}}
  HEAD is now at {{hash}} {{commit}}
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "created production branch"
$ HEAD detached from origin/production
  nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git push origin production
  error: src refspec production does not match any.
  error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/{{username}}/{{git}}
```

There are some warnings not sure how to fix / what they mean?

Comment: You are not currently on a branch (»detached head«). You want a tracking branch (`git checkout --track origin/whatever`) or if you create a new branch `git checkout -b whatever`

Comment: after doing that I receive `git push origin production
To https://github.com/chevalierc/{repo}.git
 ! [rejected]        production -> production (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/chevalierc/{repo}.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
`

Answer (score 0):

What I should have done from the start:

`$ git checkout -b production2 {{hash of commit I want}}`

and to clean up my mistakes I did the following:

```
$ git push origin --delete production
$ git branch -m production2 production
$ git push origin production
$ git push origin --delete production2
```